# Question from Oxford TSA

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's the question:

Two trains, a high-speed Train A, and a slower local train B, travel from Manchester to London. Train A travels the first 20km at 100km/hr and then at an average speed of 150km/hour. Train B travels at a constant average speed of 90km/hr.
If Train B leaves 20 minutes before Train A, at what distance will Train A pass Train B?

A: 75km  B: 90km  C: 100km  D: 120km

Given that I only have 80 seconds to do this, I'd appreciate it if someone could break it down for me and advise me on what strategy to use when approaching these sorts of questions <3

Comment: Are you using this post as an illustration to your comrades of the futility of posting an assignment to this site?

Comment: Posting hearts is a bit inappropriate and childish. I'm a student just like you. Would you put hearts in a mail to your professor?

Comment: Excellent thing I'm not speaking to my professor and that this is an open question in an open forum to anyone interested in maths - hence the heart to show appreciation

Answer (score 1):

- When Train A leaves, Train B has travelled $90\times \frac{20}{60}=30$km ahead
- When Train A reaches $20$km  after $\frac{20}{100}=0.2$ hours ($24$ minutes), Train B has travelled an extra $90 \times 0.2=18$km so is $30+18-20=28$km ahead
- Train A then takes $\frac{28}{150-90}\approx 0.46667$ hours ($28$ minutes) more to catch up with Train B, travelling $150 \times 0.46667=70$km extra while Train B travels $90 \times 0.46667=42$km extra.
- So the total distance each travels is $20+70 = 30+18+42 = 90$km

Apparently this is what you need to know if you want to do Economics at Oxford

Comment: I would have thought Oxford had an honor code. Did you think the "80 seconds" had passed?

Comment: @JohnDouma Oxford apparently only has an hono*u*r code for open book exams. Otherwise you are expecte4d just to obey the rules. The Thinking Skills Assessment is not open book, and will not be if the lockdown is lifted by 4 November

Answer (score 1):

When A starts moving, B is already 30 km ahead. At 100 kph, A takes only 12 minutes to travel the first 20 km. In this time, B travels 18 km. Now, the distance between them has closed to 28 km. A is now traveling 60 kph faster than B, so it will take 28 more minutes to close the 28 km gap, during which it will travel 70 additional km. Thus, the answer is $20 + 70 = \boxed{\text{(B) }90\text { km}}$